# Use the definition derivative to differentiate $f(x) = x^3$.

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives, solution-verification

> Differentiate the function $f(x)=x^3$ at the point $a$. Use the definition of the derivative for this question.

I know that the definition of the derivative is:$$f'(x) = \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$$

The function is $f(x)=x^3$.

I know that $h$ means $\Delta x$. I know that $\Delta x$ means $\Delta x = x_2-x_1 \implies x_2 = x_1 + \Delta x$

I'm just not sure how to obtain the derivative of the function that has an exponent.

Here is my attempt:

$$f'(x) = \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{x^3(x+x^3+x^3)-x^3}{h}$$
Then I got:
$$f'(x) = \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{x^3(x + 2 x^3)-x^3}{2x^3}$$
Simplified:
$$f'(x) = \lim_{h\to 0}= x$$

I know I did something wrong, because WolframeAlpha says:$$\frac{d}{dx}(x^3) = 3 x^2$$

I just do not see where exactly I did wrong. (If the problem is obvious and I did not see it, I am sorry, but I am currently clueless on how to solve this.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $f(x)=x^3,f(x+h)=(x+h)^3,$

$f(x+h)-f(x)=(x+h)^3-x^3=(x+h-x)\{(x+h)^2+(x+h)x+x^2\}=h\{(x+h)^2+(x+h)x+x^2\}$

So, $$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}h=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{h\{(x+h)^2+(x+h)x+x^2\}}h$$

$$=x^2+x^2+x^2$$ as $h\ne0$ as $h\to0$

---

Alternatively,
$f(x+h)-f(x)=(x+h)^3-x^3=x^3+3x^2h+3xh^2+h^3-x^3=h(3x^2+3xh+h^2)$

$$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}h=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{h(3x^2+3xh+h^2)}h=3x^2$$ as $h\ne0$ as $h\to0$

Comment: Thank you so much, I see want I did wrong.

Comment: @user67254, my pleasure. A practice of $f(x+h)$ based on $f(x)$ can be handy. Like for $f(x)=x^x,x^{\sin x},\cos(\ln x)$ etc.

Answer (score 5):

Using the Identity

$$a^3-b^3=(a-b)(a^2+a\cdot b+b^2)$$

We can solve the derivative of

$$f(x)=x^3$$

using the definition of derivative

$$f'(x) = \lim_{h\to0}{\frac{f(x+h) - f(x)}{h}}$$
$$=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{(x+h-x)((x+h)^2+(x+h)\cdot(x)+x^2)}{h}$$
$$=\lim_{h\to0}((x+h)^2+(x+h)\cdot(x)+x^2)$$
$$=(x)^2+(x)\cdot(x)+x^2$$
$$=3\cdot x^2$$

Answer (score 1):

Where this $x^3(x+x^3+x^3)$ is coming from? You'd rather *substitue* $(x+h)$ in place of $x$ when $f$ is to be applied:

$$f(x+h)=(x+h)^3=x^3+3x^2h+3xh^2+h^3\,.$$

Answer (score 0):

Without the common definition of the derivative with $h$ and binomial expansion, derivation looks simpler:
$$f'(x)=(x^3)'=\lim_{y\to x}\frac{y^3-x^3}{y-x}=\lim_{y\to x}y^2+yx+x^2=3x^2$$

Note that at $x=a$, $f'(a)=3a^2$.